Docker build often crashes with "Add failed: unexpected EOF"
One particular CI job (on our self-hosted GitLab cluster with many beefy runner servers) which downloads and ADDs large (14GB) file crashes most of the time with
Step 5/5 : ADD https://whatver/file.foo
Downloading [==============>            ]  7.919GB/13.86GB
ADD failed: unexpected EOF

and sometimes it works without any errors
Step 5/5 : ADD https://whatver/file.foo
Downloading [==========================>]  13.86GB/13.86GB

All CI machines have plenty of free disk space (>200GB) and I can fully reproduce the behaviour above by doing the build manually directly on the machines.
I read that there are some known issues in the Docker build process in specific versions with TAR files when they are automatically unpacked but in our case it's not a TAR, just a big binary file.
What exactly is happening here? I assume it has something to do with some allocated disk space but could not find anything related.
There is some disk (storage) space settings mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/garbage-collection/ but does not seem to be related. I am talking about the defaultKeepStorage and keepStorage options.

Unexpected EOF sounds like an error on a read operation. So I don't think it's disk space since that would be on a write operation. I would investigate the web server serving the file and/or see if there are network stability issues.

OK thanks, I'll check!

That sounds to me a little bit more like a network hiccup.  They do happen even on "good" networks, and trying to move multi-gigabyte files over HTTP can make them visible like this.  Historically I've run into similar problems pushing and pulling similar resulting Docker images and it's looked very much like this; ~1 GB seemed to be the practical limit on an individual layer (not a technical limit, but the network operation would frequently fail if it was larger).

Indeed I think both of you are right. However, I could not reproduce the problem when doing sftp directly on the machine (without using a Docker container). I made 100 downloads of the 14GB file with MD5 check and not a single error. In a Docker container, it's something like 10% success rate. Very weird!
